# Node.js - wait for multiple async calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to make multiple MongoDB queries before I render a Jade template, but I can't quite figure out how to wait until all the Mongo Queries are completed before rendering the template.

```
exports.init = function(req, res){


    var NYLakes = {};
    var NJLakes = {};
    var filterNY = {"State" : "NY"};
    db.collection('lakes').find(filterNY).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        NYLakes = result;
    });

    var filterNJ = {"State" : "NJ"};
    db.collection('lakes').find(filterNJ).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        NJLakes = result;
    });

    res.render('explore/index', {
            NYlakes: NYLakes,
            NJlakes: NJLakes
    });

};
```

Answer (score 58):

I'm a big fan of underscore/lodash, so I usually use `_.after`, which creates a function that only executes after being called a certain number of times.

```
var finished = _.after(2, doRender);

asyncMethod1(data, function(err){
  //...
  finished();
});

asyncMethod2(data, function(err){
  //...
  finished();
})

function doRender(){
  res.render(); // etc
}
```

Since javascript hoists the definition of functions defined with the `function funcName()` syntax, your code reads naturally: top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you want to run the two operations in parallel rather than waiting for one to finish before starting the next, you'll need to track how many operations have completed in each callback.

In raw node.js javascript, one way to do this would be this:

```
exports.init = function(req, res){
    var NYLakes = null;
    var NJLakes = null;
    var filterNY = {"State" : "NY"};

    db.collection('lakes').find(filterNY).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        NYLakes = result;
        complete();
    });

    var filterNJ = {"State" : "NJ"};
    db.collection('lakes').find(filterNJ).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        NJLakes = result;
        complete();
    });

    function complete() {
        if (NYLakes !== null && NJLakes !== null) {
            res.render('explore/index', {
                NYlakes: NYLakes,
                NJlakes: NJLakes
            });
        }
    }

};
```

Basically what's happening here is that you check at the end of each operation if all of them have finished, and at that point you finish off the operation.

If you're doing a lot of these things, take a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library as an example of a tool to make it easier to manage this sort of thing.

Comment: This would have a race condition. If both async operations execute up until right before they call complete(), then they could both call it with the necessary condition to execute the body of the if statement in complete(). Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @ghert85 In a multithreaded environment you'd be right, but node.js is single threaded. So the code cannot be interrupted until after it returns to the event loop and this race condition cannot occur.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module:

```
var states = [{"State" : "NY"},{"State" : "NJ"}];

var findLakes = function(state,callback){
  db.collection('lakes').find(state).toArray(callback);
}

async.map(states, findLakes , function(err, results){
    // do something with array of results
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait.for https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

**using Wait.for:**

```
exports.init = function(req, res){

    var NYLakes = {};
    var NJLakes = {};

    var coll = db.collection('lakes');

    var filterNY = {"State" : "NY"};
    var a = wait.forMethod(coll,'find',filterNY);
    NYLakes = wait.forMethod(a,'toArray');

    var filterNJ = {"State" : "NJ"};
    var b = wait.forMethod(coll,'find',filterNJ);
    NJLakes = wait.forMethod(b,'toArray');

    res.render('explore/index',
        {
            NYlakes: NYLakes,
            NJlakes: NJLakes
        }
    );

};
```

**Requesting in parallel using wait.for parallel map:**

```
exports.init = function(req, res){

    var coll = db.collection('lakes');

    //execute in parallel, wait for results
    var result = wait.parallel.map(
                    [{coll:coll,filter:{"State" : "NY"}}
                    , {coll:coll,filter:{"State" : "NJ"}}]
                    , getData);

    res.render('explore/index',
        {
            NYlakes: result[0],
            NJlakes: result[1]
        }
    );

};

//map function
function getData(item,callback){
try{
    var a = wait.forMethod(item.coll,'find',item.filter);
    var b = wait.forMethod(a,'toArray');
    callback (null, b);
} catch(err){
    callback(err);
}
```

I'm not familiar with mongo, so you may have to adjust the calls.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the least lines of code using await:

```
var async = require("async"); //include async module
...
async function getData() { //make sure to use async function
  var NYlakes = await db.collection('lakes').find(filterNY); //can append additional logic after the find() 
  var NJlakes = await db.collection('lakes').find(filterNJ);

  res.json({"NYLakes": NYLakes, "NJLakes": NJLakes}); //render response
}

getData();
```

Side note: In this case await is serving as a `Promise.all()` be careful not to abuse the await function.