# Returning multiple datasets to a Node.js View

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is in my `routes/product.js` file in my node.js/express project which is using express-myconnection.  How do I return multiple data sets for the view to use?  I have the `data` object and the `dropdown` object being populated by the same query.  I want to keep the `data` object like it is, but populate the `dropdown` object with a different query.

```
exports.edit = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ?', [id], function (err, rows) {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
            res.render('products\\edit', {
                page_title: "Product : Edit",
                save_button_title: "Update",
                data: rows,
                dropdown:rows});
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either nest another database call inside your first "success" area or you can try something like this:
[Node.js - wait for multiple async calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008479/node-js-wait-for-multiple-async-calls)