# node.js async request with timeout?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Is it possible, in node.js, to make an asynchronous call that times out if it takes too long (or doesn't complete) and triggers a default callback?

The details:

I have a node.js server that receives a request and then makes multiple requests asynchronously behind the scenes, before responding. The basic issue is covered by an [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008479/node-js-wait-for-multiple-async-calls) question, but some of these calls are considered 'nice to have'. What I mean is that if we get the response back, then it enhances the response to the client, but if they take too long to respond it is better to respond to the client in a timely manner than with those responses.

At the same time this approach would allow to protect against services that simply aren't completing or failing, while allowing the main thread of operation to respond.

You can think of this in the same way as a Google search that has one core set of results, but provides extra responses based on other behind the scenes queries.

Comment: Check async module https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Sure it's possible. Just put a `setTimeout` and figure out which callback is invoked first (the timeout or the request). Or simply use promises and `Promise.race` them against each other.

Comment: @Bergi 's idea of `Promise.race` is the cleanest solution.. well, well worth learning the PromiseAPI.

Comment: Just to jump on the `Promise.race` band wagon, checkout the [MDN Docs for `Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race).Its a simpler and cleaner approach considering how complicated or error prone the already given answers are. An even better approach would be Bluebird's `Promise.any()` as it has a couple improvements over the standard A+ race method as described [here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.race.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its simple just use setTimout

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var result = {};
    // populate object
    http.get('http://www.google.com/index.html', (res) => {
        result.property = response;
        return res.send(result);
    });
    // if we havent returned within a second, return without data
    setTimeout(function(){
        return res.send(result);
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Edit**: as mentioned by peteb i forgot to check to see if we already sent. This can be accomplished by using res.headerSent or by maintaining a 'sent' value yourself. I also noticed res variable was being reassigned

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var result = {};
    // populate object
    http.get('http://www.google.com/index.html', (httpResponse) => {
        result.property = httpResponse;
        if(!res.headersSent){
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
    // if we havent returned within a second, return without data
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!res.headersSent){
            res.send(result);
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Is it ok to call `res.send` twice?

Comment: This will result in an error being through by `res.send()` in the `http.get()` callback if `setTimeout()` is called already. A check of `res.headersSent` before the `res.send()` in the `http.get()` callback is necessary as well as `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a timeout. For example using the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method:

- Setup a timeout handler: var timeOutX = setTimeout(function…
- Set that variable to null: timeOutX = NULL (to indicate that the timeout has been fired)
- Then execute your callback function with one argument (error handling): callback({error:'The async request timed out'});
- You add the time for your timeout function, for example 3 seconds

Something like this:

```
var timeoutX = setTimeout(function() {
    timeOutX = null;

    yourCallbackFunction({error:'The async request timed out'});

}, 3000);
```

- With that set, you can then call your async function and you put a timeout check to make sure that your timeout handler didn’t fire yet.
  Finally, before you run your callback function, you must clear that scheduled timeout handler using the [clearTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) method.

Something like this:

```
yourAsyncFunction(yourArguments, function() {
    if (timeOutX) {
        clearTimeout(timeOutX);
        yourCallbackFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example of timeout callback https://github.com/jakubknejzlik/node-timeout-callback/blob/master/index.js

You could modify it to do action if time's out or just simply catch error.